# How to auto-total form calculation with dropdown and radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a booking form which is showing the total cost of a camp before confirm. My problem is I can write a script to display how the form looks but it's not work.

Here's my script:

**HTML**

```
<td>Student</td>
<td>
    <select name="stu" id="Student">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>Teacher</td>
<td>
    <select name="tchr" id="Teacher">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>House Type</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="accom" value="100" id="a1">
    <label for="a1">Hotel</label>
    <input type="radio" name="accom" value="0" id="a2">
    <label for="a2">House</label>
</td>
<td>Accommodation</td>
<td>
    <span id="zStay">0</span>
</td>
<td>Total</td>
<td>
    <span id="total1">0</span>
</td>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var nTchr = 0;
    var nStu = 0;
    var nStay = 0;

    $("#Teacher").change(function () {
        nTchr = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        calcTotals();
    });
    $("#Student").change(function () {
        nStu = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        calcTotals();
    });

    $('input[name=accom]').change(function (evt) {
        nStay = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        calcTotals();
    });

    function calcTotals() {
        var zStay = nStay * (nStu + nTchr);
        $('#zStay').number(zStay);
        $("#total01").number(zStay + 60 * nTchr + 150 * nStu);
        $("#total1").val(zStay + 60 * nTchr + 150 * nStu);
    }
});
```

Where `$.number()` is a plug-in, for reference:

```js
$.fn.number = function (number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
    var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
        prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
        sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
        dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
        s = '',
        toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
            var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
            return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
        };
    // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
    s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
    if (s[0].length > 3) {
        s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
    }
    if ((s[1] || '').length > prec) {
        s[1] = s[1] || '';
        s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
    }
    // Add this number to the element as text.
    this.text(s.join(dec));
};
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/8u26ozh3/

To be straight :

1. Why it's not working
2. How to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 $(window).load(function(){...})
```

with

```
 $(function(){...})
```

where's the element with total01 id?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t3y3a62p/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace:

```
$(window).load(function () {
```

witk:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your code,i got the output

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    </head>


<body id="contextmenu">
    <form>
        <table border width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>Student</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="stu" id="Student">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Teacher</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="tchr" id="Teacher">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>House Type</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="accom" value="100" id="a1">
                    <label for="a1">Hotel</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="accom" value="0" id="a2">
                    <label for="a2">House</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Accommodation</td>
                <td>
                    <span id="zStay">0</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td>
                    <span id="total1">0</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <script lang=JavaScript>

        $.fn.number = function (number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
            number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
            var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
                prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
                sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
                dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
                s = '',
                toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
                    var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
                    return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
                };
            // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
            s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
            if (s[0].length > 3) {
                s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
            }
            if ((s[1] || '').length > prec) {
                s[1] = s[1] || '';
                s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
            }
            // Add this number to the element as text.
            this.text(s.join(dec));
        };


        $(window).load(function () {
            var nTchr = 0;
            var nStu = 0;
            var nStay = 0;

            $("#Teacher").on('change', function () {
                nTchr = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
                calcTotals();
            });
            $("#Student").on('change', function () {
                nStu = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
                calcTotals();
            });

            $('input[name=accom]').on('change', function (evt) {
                nStay = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
                calcTotals();
            });

            function calcTotals() {
                var zStay =parseInt(nStay * (nStu + nTchr));
                $('#zStay').text(zStay);
                $("#total01").text(zStay + 60 * nTchr + 150 * nStu);
                $("#total1").text(zStay + 60 * nTchr + 150 * nStu);
            }
        }); //]]>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can check this http://jsfiddle.net/cd7v9bfm/   you load script inside onDomready